# Login failed for user 'dbAdmin'

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, web-services, wcf

I've been all around google and this site trying suggestions to fix the error I am currently getting:

> "Can not open connection! Login failed for user 'dbAdmin'.
>
> Connection: Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=stantecUsers;User Id=dbAdmin;Password=123456789;"

I created a login for my **MS SQL 2012 EXPRESS** adding **dbAdmin** as the user:
[image]

And I also made sure the database was using both SQL server and Windows Auth Mode:
[image]
[image]

And for my WCF web service I have the following connection string:

```
try
{
   string connetionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;" + 
                             "Initial Catalog=stantecUsers;" +
                             "User Id=dbAdmin;" +
                             "Password=123456789;";
   string sql = "SELECT * " +
                "FROM [stantecUsers].[dbo].[users] AS stantecUsers " +
                "INNER JOIN [stantecUsers].[dbo].[usersData] AS stantecUserData " +
                "ON stantecUsers.link2Data = stantecUserData.link2Data " +
                "WHERE stantecUsers.phoneNum = '" + phoneNum + "' " +
                "ORDER BY stantecUsers.ID ASC;";
   SqlConnection connection;
   SqlCommand command;
   connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);

   // Create a new object that matches the structure of the JSON file.
  var root = new RootObject
  {
      DATA = new DATA { clocked = new List<Clocked>() }
  };

  try
  {
      connection.Open();
      command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
      SqlDataReader read = command.ExecuteReader();

      while (read.Read())
      {
         root.DATA.firstName = read["firstName"].ToString();
         root.DATA.lastName = read["lastName"].ToString();
         root.DATA.phoneNum = read["phoneNum"].ToString();
         root.DATA.title = read["title"].ToString();
         root.DATA.emailAddress = read["emailAddress"].ToString();
         root.DATA.image = read["image"].ToString();
         root.DATA.clocked.Add(new Clocked { 
              date = read["theDate"].ToString(), 
              type = read["theType"].ToString() 
         });
       }

       read.Close();
       command.Dispose();
       connection.Close();
                
       return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root, Formatting.Indented);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       return "Can not open connection! " + ex.Message + "  Connection: " + connetionString;
   }
}
catch (SqlException e)
{
   return e.Message;
}
```

I'm not sure where I need to go from here in order to fix the issue it seems to continuously have so help would be great!

**UPDATE: when trying to add user under database:**
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you able to connect to the database from management console using the above uid/pw?

Comment: @KosalaW No it does not seem that i can...

Comment: That means this problem has nothing to do with C#. Check if you can see dbAdmin user in your databases users list. If not right click and add dbAdmin to your database users list. If it's available, check if you have given dbreader and dbwriter access to dbAdmin.

Comment: Didn't i already do that (add dbAdmin) in my first screen shot I posted?

Comment: I don't think you did. You have to expand the `Databases`, select your database, then expand `Security >  Users` under your database.

Comment: @KosalaW Please see my OP for an update. Doesn't seem to let me do that.

Comment: According to the last picture, you have already given necessary access rights. Are you still getting the same error when you try to login from Management Console? It may be worth changing the password and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oddly enough it seemed I had to add **"db_owner"** to my database security settings for the user and under **Owned Schemas** in order for it to work correctly...
[image]